# How to generate in PHP a series of HTML pages based on CSV data?

Tags: php, html, csv

A problem: it is necessary to generate in PHP script the series of HTML pages with data output from each row of data in CSV (TITLE, DESCRIPTION, H1, IMG, Text, A HREF = "URL").

```
$image_number
$image_name
$title
$description
$image_source
$keywords
$url
$page_name
```

That is, in fact, each line in CSV, when processed in PHP>, gives pages to the gallery> HTML or PHP directory according to a given single template, i.e. each individual physical page ($ Page Name at the specified address on the server) with data from the CSV file of this string values ​​of each variable: $ title, $ description, $ h1, $ image_source, $ keywords, $ image (number), $ url = ...

This is necessary for indexing in Google Images, but there is no point in communicating with MySQL to process queries yet.

CSV directory: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F_zWVaFDtjp82NDMZdvhWHyB1GYq4BmG/view?usp=sharing

Sample PHP code * for processing CSV and unloading template pages: (* as I understood - and wrote, probably there are errors).

```
<?php
    function CSVtoHTML {
        $row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen ("catalog.csv", "r"))! == FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv ($handle, 30, ","))! == FALSE) {
    for each ($row[i]) {
                $column[1] = $image_number;
                $column[2] = $image_name;
                $column[3] = $title;
                $column[4] = $description;
                $column[5] = $image_source;
                $column[6] = $url;
                $column[7] = $page_name;
                $content = '<! doctype html>
                <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
                        <title>'.$title.'</title>
                        <meta description = "'.$ description.'" />
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1> '.$h1.'</h1>
                            <img src = "'.$image_source.'" alt = "">
                            <h2> '.$image_name.' </h2>
                            <p> Keywords: '.$keywords.' </p>
                            <p> <a href="/register?value='.$image_number.'"> Buy now </a> </p>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html> ';
/ * How to write data in HTML with UTF-8 encoding to a folder on the server with a given name? * /
                $htmldata = file_get_contents ($content);
                $htmldata = mb_convert_encoding ($htmldata, 'UTF-8');
                file_put_contents ('graphics/'.$page_name.'.html', $htmldata);
           }
           fclose ($handle);
       }
       return $data;
       echo "Catalog generated now"
    }
    else {
        echo "Catalog in CSV is empty or broken."
    }
}
?>
```

Each line in CSV, when processed in PHP, outputs pages to the graphics in HTML directory according to a given single template, i.e. each individual physical page (name $ page_name at the specified address on the server) with data from the CSV file of the given string, the values ​​of each variable: $title, $description, $h1, $image_source, $keywords, $image (number), $url = ...

This is necessary for indexing in Google Images, but there is no point in communicating with MySQL to process queries yet.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off making something dynamic rather than creating .html files but to answer.

First row is the header, store it in a variable then use it with [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) with the row to create your associative array, though you could just access by index.

```
<?php
function CSVtoHTML() {
    $row = 0;
    $header = [];
    if (($handle = fopen("catalog.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            // first line is header, grab it then continue
            if ( $row === 0) {
                $header = $data;
                $row++;
                continue;
            }

            // make associative array from header and data
            $data = array_combine($header, $data);

            // make document (you need to work on this, but your see var is accessed by header name)
            $content = '<!doctype html>
                <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
                        <title>'.$data['Title'].'</title>
                        <meta description = "'.$data['Description'].'" />
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1> '.$data['Title'].'</h1>
                            <img src="'.$data['Image Source'].'" alt>
                            <h2> '.$data['Image Name'].' </h2>
                            <p> Keywords: '.$data['Keywords'].' </p>
                            <p> <a href="/register?value='.$data['Image Number'].'"> Buy now </a> </p>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html> ';

            // make the file
            file_put_contents('./graphics/'.$data['Page Name'], $content);

            $row++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

// and don't forget to call it
CSVtoHTML();
```

Comment: I tested it now. It not save the pages in html: [link]https://bundlespace.com/script-parser, base: [link]https://bundlespace.com/imagebase.csv

Comment: It works > only adds:    $filedata = file_get_contents($content);
   $filedata = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8');
   file_put_contents(''.$data['Page Name'], $filedata);